# Pass a function with parameters to a VoidCallback

Tags: dart, flutter

Is it possible to pass a Function with parameters to a VoidCallback?

for example something like this:

```
class MyClass {
  void doSomething(int i){

  }

  MyOtherClass myOtherClass = new MyOtherClass(doSomething);
}


class MyOtherClass {
  final VoidCallback callback(int);

  MyOtherClass(this.callback);

  callback(5);
}
```

Comment: More advanced function can be one that accepts 2 String and return int `final int Function(String, String) callback`

Answer (score 168, accepted):

The declaration of `VoidCallback` is

```
typedef void VoidCallback();
```

That is the type of functions that can be called with zero arguments and which does not return a useful value. That does not seem to be what you want.
It's not entirely clear what you do want since the program isn't syntactically valid, but would this work for you:

```
class MyClass { 
  static doSomething(int i) { /* ... */ }
  MyOtherClass myOtherClass = new MyOtherClass(doSomething);
}
class MyOtherClass {
  final void Function(int) callback;
  MyOtherClass(this.callback);
  void callCallaback() { callback(5); }
}
```

Here we define the type of the `callback` field to be the type of functions that can be called with one integer argument and which returns no useful value. The `doSomething` method has that type, so it can be assigned to `callback`.

You could also use a typedef to name the function:

```
typedef Int2VoidFunc = void Function(int);
// or: typedef void Int2VoidFunc(int arg);
class MyOtherClass {
  final Int2VoidFunc callback;
  MyOtherClass(this.callback);
  void callCallaback() { callback(5); }
}
```

The effect is exactly the same, it just allows you to use a shorter name for the function type, but that only really makes sense if you use it a lot.

Answer (score 57):

Example in UI case; you may need create widget and pass click function.

**Step 1:** create widget with function as parameter in constructor:

```
Container _cardButton({
  Function onClickAction,
}) {
  return Container(
    width: 340,
    height: 90,
    child: InkWell(
      splashColor: Colors.blue.withAlpha(30),
      onTap: () {
        onClickAction();
      },
      child: Card(
        elevation: 5,
        child: somechild,
      ),
    ),
  );
```

**Step 2:** implement widget to the three view and pass function like this:

```
_cardButton(
    onClickAction: () => {debugPrint("CLICKED")},
),
```

Comment: It is what I was looking for. So Thank you!

Answer (score 45):

create your own callback instead

```
typedef void MyCallback(int foo);

class MyClass {
  void doSomething(int i){

  }

  MyOtherClass myOtherClass = new MyOtherClass(doSomething);
}


class MyOtherClass {
  final MyCallback callback;

  MyOtherClass(this.callback);

}
```

Comment: in my use case, i want to make MyCallback accepts any type of arguments, so I tried to make the parameter dynamic instead of int , but it didn't work

Comment: it produces the following error:The argument type 'void Function(Source)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(dynamic)'.

Answer (score 18):

Just replace VoidCallback with Function(int)

```
class MyClass {
  void doSomething(int i){

  }

  MyOtherClass myOtherClass = new MyOtherClass(doSomething);
}


class MyOtherClass {
 //OP code (does not work): final VoidCallback callback(int); 
 final Function(int) callback;

  MyOtherClass(this.callback);

  callback(5);
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Flutter already has a typedef for this: [`ValueSetter`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/foundation/ValueSetter.html).

So you can pass an instance of `ValueSetter<int>` to your other class.

Comment: How to do multiple arguments? like int And String?

Comment: @JeffreyLiu You could create a type to hold those values. Then use `ValueSetter<YourTypeHere>`.

Comment: what if i want it to accept any type, can I make it dynamic.ValueSetter<dynamic>

Answer (score 15):

Instead of `VoidCallback`, you can use `ValueChanged<T>`, here is an example:

```
class MyClass {
  static void doSomething(int i) {}

  MyOtherClass myOtherClass = MyOtherClass(doSomething);
}

class MyOtherClass {
  final ValueChanged<int> callback;

  MyOtherClass(this.callback);
}
```

---

You can then call `callback` with any `int` value

```
callback(10);
```

Answer (score 8):

Simple way to do to is create a stateless or stateful widget and pass callback function into it. Consider a code snippet like a below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestFunctionWidget extends StatelessWidget {
final Function onCallback;
 const TestFunctionWidget({
  Key key,
  this.onCallback,
 }) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    this.onCallback();
  },
  child: Container(
    child: Text("Test Call Back"),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Now to use it in a screen consider a code snippet.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:netflix_clone/pages/test_widget.dart';

class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
 TestScreen({
 Key key,
 }) : super(key: key);
 @override
_TestScreen1State createState() => _TestScreen1State();
}
class _TestScreen1State extends State<TestScreen> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return TestFunctionWidget(
  onCallback: () {
    // To do
  },
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

1) Create typedef first in any constant class:

```
typedef StringVoidFunc = void Function(String);
```

2) Pass from calling function class one

```
showAlertDialog(doSomething);
```

3) Call back handle Function

```
void doSomething(String i){
Navigator.pop(context);
setState(() {

});
```

}

4) From where you want to fire call back from Class Two

```
    showAlertDialog(StringVoidFunc callback) {
     callback("delete");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ways that I use:

1 - Declare with typedef:

```
typedef MyFunction = void Function(int);

class MyClass {
    final MyFunction myFunction;
    
    void onBunttonPressed() {
        //using function
        myFunction(1);
    }
}
```

2 - Direct in variable:

```
class MyClass {
    final void Function(int) myFunction;
        
    void onBunttonPressed() {
        //using function
        myFunction(1);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 // We can pass function  like this too....   
class A
{
void showMessage(BuildContext context, String message) {
       ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
       SnackBar(
         content: Text(message),
         duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
         action: SnackBarAction(
         textColor: Colors.blue,
         label: 'OKAY',
         onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
   );
}
// calling another class and passing function
EditPage(     
        showMessage: (String message) {
          showMessage(context, message);
        },
      )
}
class EditPage{
final Function showMessage;
 EditPage({required this.showMessage})

}
// we can call by
widget.showMessage(context,'message value');
```