# How to access to a method in a statefull widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to access this method `updateCounter()` from another class. How should I call it? Or how can I instantiate `_HomePageState`?

Here is my code :

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
   static int i=0;
   void updateCounter(int counter) {
    print(counter);
    setState(() {
      i=counter;  
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50085748/7666442

Comment: Yes, but I have this issue with statefullWidget class

Comment: its doesn't matter if you use `statefullWidget` or `stateless` widget still you can pass your method as argument