# The argument type 'void Function()?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(String)?'

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm getting this error trying to apply the concept of reusable component.
can some one help please?
I need to make both the onFieldSubmitted and onChanged a optional functions.
also I tried just using Function to declear name of the function instead of VoidCallback but it didn't word.
this is the code

```
Widget defaultTextBox({
  required TextEditingController inputController,
  required String boxLapel,
  VoidCallback? onSubmit,
  VoidCallback? changed,
  required VoidCallback pressed,
}) =>
    TextFormField(
      validator: (value) {
        if (value!.isEmpty) {
          return 'please enter password address';
        }
        return null;
      },
      controller: inputController,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: boxLapel,
          labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(9.0))),
          suffixIcon: IconButton(
            onPressed: pressed,
            icon: Icon(
               Icons.visibility),
          ),
          prefixIcon: Icon(
            Icons.lock,
            color: Colors.black,
          )),
      obscureText: true,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
       // error is here and here 
      onFieldSubmitted: onSubmit, // <-
      onChanged: changed, // <-
    );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass a function with parameters to a VoidCallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50085748/pass-a-function-with-parameters-to-a-voidcallback)

Comment: try to provide some variables in the callback like..
`onFieldSubmitted: (value1) => onSubmit()`
`onChanged: (value2) => onChanged()`

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution and I should declare the function as follow :

```
required String? Function(String?)? onSubmit,
```