# access a variable value in list item element button click

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview

I have a LIST widget in my feed class for building post from firebase.
The list has a class to show how the each element of list should look named Attend.

```
Container buildUserPosts() {
  Future<List<Attend>> getPosts() async {
   **this is the variable which I want to access in Attend class**
    String? datatopass = widget.sub;
    List<Attend> posts = [];
    var snap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Attend')
        .orderBy("username")
        .get();

    for (var doc in snap.docs) {
      posts.add(Attend.fromDocument(doc));
    }
 
    return posts.reversed.toList();
  }
   return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder<List<Attend>>(
    future: getPosts(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return Container(
            alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
            child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }  else {
        return Column(
            children: snapshot.data!.map((Attend imagePost) {
          return imagePost;
        }).toList());
      }
 
    .....code for checking empty by if else and return
return Column(
            children: snapshot.data!.map((Attend imagePost) {
          return imagePost;
        }).toList());
```

Now the issue is that I want to **access a variable of feed class named *datatopass* in** my each element of list **Attend**.But I am not able to figure how to pass that variable in my list item ,as the list gets data through firebase and gets generate.

My Attend class

```
    class Attend extends StatefulWidget {
  const Attend(
      { this.imageUrl,
        this.username,
        this.userphone,
        this.postId,
        this.ownerId});

  factory Attend.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot document) {
    return Attend(
      username: document['username'],
      imageUrl: document['imageUrl'],
      userphone: document['userphone'],
      postId: document.id,
      ownerId: document['ownerId'],
    );
  }

  final String? imageUrl;
  final String? username;
  final String? userphone;
  final String? postId;
  final String? ownerId;

  _Attend createState() => _Attend(
        imageUrl: this.imageUrl,
        username: this.username,
        userphone: this.userphone,
        ownerId: this.ownerId,
        postId: this.postId,
      );
}
```

In the  class,I had created a button and I want that variable value in it.

Comment: What if you passed in a callback function?

Comment: Pls ,can.you elaborate.what are you trying to explain in sense of code in my one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50085748/pass-a-function-with-parameters-to-a-voidcallback/50085960

Comment: no voidcall back not working, can you suggest ay different way ,or creating any variable and accessing it in attend post.