# setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build. I've tried WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback but then my buttons do not works

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

```
import 'package:customizedapp/reuseable_card.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'icon_content.dart';
import 'constants.dart';

enum Gender {
  male,
  female,
}

class InputPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const InputPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<InputPage> createState() => _InputPageState();
}

class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
  Gender? selectedGender;
  double height = 0.0;
  int weight = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            'BMI Calculator',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
          ),
        ),
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: ReusableCard(
                      colour: selectedGender == Gender.male
                          ? kActiveReusealeContainerColor
                          : kInactiveReusealeContainerColor,
                      containChild: IconContent(FontAwesomeIcons.mars, 'MALE'),
                      onPress: () {
                        setState(() {
                          selectedGender = Gender.male;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: ReusableCard(
                      colour: selectedGender == Gender.female
                          ? kActiveReusealeContainerColor
                          : kInactiveReusealeContainerColor,
                      containChild:
                          IconContent(FontAwesomeIcons.venus, 'FEMALE'),
                      onPress: () {
                        setState(() {
                          selectedGender = Gender.female;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ReusableCard(
                colour: kActiveReusealeContainerColor,
                containChild: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Height',
                      style: kLabelTextStyle,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
                      textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          height.toStringAsFixed(2),
                          style: kNumberDisplayTextStyle,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'ft',
                          style: kLabelTextStyle,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SliderTheme(
                      data: SliderThemeData(
                        activeTrackColor: Colors.white,
                        inactiveTrackColor: Color(0xff8E8E9C),
                        thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(
                            enabledThumbRadius: 12.0, elevation: 5),
                        overlayShape:
                            RoundSliderOverlayShape(overlayRadius: 24),
                        thumbColor: Color(0xffDF4068),
                        overlayColor: Color(0x29DF4068),
                      ),
                      child: Slider(
                          value: height,
                          min: kMinSliderValue,
                          max: kMaxSliderValue,
                          onChanged: (double newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              height = newValue;
                            });
                          }),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: ReusableCard(
                      colour: kActiveReusealeContainerColor,
                      containChild: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            'Weight',
                            style: kLabelTextStyle,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            weight.toString(),
                            style: kNumberDisplayTextStyle,
                          ),
```

'here in the row I'm getting error, i've tried by wrapping row and children in Expanded widget but doesn't works either'

```
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              RoundButton(
                                  icon: FontAwesomeIcons.add,
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      weight++;
                                    });
                                  }),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 10,
                              ),
                              RoundButton(
                                  icon: FontAwesomeIcons.minus,
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      weight--;
                                    });
                                  }),
                            ],
                            
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: ReusableCard(
                      colour: kActiveReusealeContainerColor,
                      containChild: Container(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: kBottomContainerHeight,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
              width: double.infinity,
              color: kBottomContainerColor,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RoundButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const RoundButton({Key? key, required this.icon, required this.onPressed})
      : super(key: key);
  final IconData icon;
  final Function onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RawMaterialButton(
        onPressed: onPressed(),
        child: Icon(icon),
        fillColor: kInactiveReusealeContainerColor,
        constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 56, minHeight: 56),
        shape: CircleBorder());
  }
}
```

'this error occurs'

> This InputPage widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
> The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was: InputPage
> state: _InputPageState#98c9c
> The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was: RoundButton
> dirty'

Answer (score 1):

Replace `onPressed: onPressed(),` with `onPressed: onPressed,`. You like to call the event when the button is pressed instead of build time.

Comment: What's the difference I'm new it'll help, if you'll elaborate.

Comment: once you do `onPressed: onPressed()` it call the `onPressed` method on build time. and the parent widget calling setState on `weight++;`. You  can't change the state until the first frame is build. `onPressed: onPressed` mean passing a function instance, when the tap happen it will call the method

Comment: You can explore more about [Pass a function with parameters to a VoidCallback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50085748/10157127)

Comment: `onPressed: onPressed` means “when the user presses the button, call the `onPressed` method. This is what you want. You are registering a reference to the method you want to be called in the future when a user presses the button. 

`onPressed: onPressed()` on the other hand, is immediately invoking the `onPressed()` method right as the build method is being executed. It’s not waiting for the user to actually press a button.